# Does NSWindow have IBAction

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

In subview of ViewController, we can specify what a form would do when the form is loaded, etc. Can we do that for NSWindow object? It looks like every time I drag and drop the only thing I can pull out is outlet.

We can usually create IBAction by Drag and Dropping with Assistant Editor.

Comment: What do you mean by "drag and drop"?

Comment: We can usually create IBAction by Drag and Dropping with Assistant Editor.